# To add values in a table with Spring+hibernate

Tags: java, spring, hibernate, spring-mvc

i am developing a code in spring + hibernate to add values in the table by fetching it from the html page but i am not able to run the controller . my code is 
    CustomList.java

```
package main.java.com.bizmerlin.learningresources.model;

import javax.persistence.Column;
import javax.persistence.Entity;
import javax.persistence.GeneratedValue;
import javax.persistence.GenerationType;
import javax.persistence.Id;
import javax.persistence.Table;

@Entity
@Table(name ="customlist")
public class CustomList {
    private Integer listid;
       private String listname;
       private Integer cid;

       public void setListId(Integer listid) {
          this.listid = listid;
       }
       public Integer getListId() {
          return listid;
       }

       public void setListName(String listname) {
          this.listname = listname;
       }
       public String getListName() {
          return listname;
       }

       public void setCid(Integer cid) {
          this.cid = cid;
       }
       public Integer getCid() {
          return cid;
       }

}
```

CustomListController

```
    package main.java.com.bizmerlin.learningresources.controller;


import java.util.List;

import main.java.com.bizmerlin.learningresources.model.CustomList;
import main.java.com.bizmerlin.learningresources.services.CustomListService;

import org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.Autowired;
import org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.Qualifier;
import org.springframework.stereotype.Controller;
import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.ModelAttribute;
import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.RequestMapping;
import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.RequestMethod;
import org.springframework.web.servlet.ModelAndView;
import org.springframework.ui.Model;
import org.springframework.ui.ModelMap;




import com.mysql.jdbc.log.Log;



    @Controller
     @RequestMapping(value= "/customlist" , method = RequestMethod.POST)
public class CustomListController {
        private CustomListService customlistservice;

        @Autowired(required=true)
        @Qualifier(value="customlistservice")
        public void setCustomListService(CustomListService customlistservice){
            this.customlistservice = customlistservice;
        }

        @RequestMapping(value= "/customlist/add", method = RequestMethod.POST)
        public String addCustomList(@ModelAttribute("customlist") CustomList customlist){

                this.customlistservice.addCustomList(customlist);

            return "redirect:/persons";

        }
    }
```

CustomListDAO

```
 package main.java.com.bizmerlin.learningresources.dao;

import java.util.List;

import main.java.com.bizmerlin.learningresources.model.CustomList;

import org.hibernate.Session;
import org.hibernate.SessionFactory;
import org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.Autowired;
import org.springframework.stereotype.Repository;
import org.springframework.transaction.annotation.Transactional;




    @Repository("customlistDAO")
    @SuppressWarnings({"unchecked", "rawtypes"})
    public interface CustomListDAO {


            public void addCustomList(CustomList customlist);

        }
```

CustomListDAOImpl.java

```
 package main.java.com.bizmerlin.learningresources.dao;

import java.util.List;

import main.java.com.bizmerlin.learningresources.model.CustomList;

import org.hibernate.Session;
import org.hibernate.SessionFactory;
import org.slf4j.Logger;
import org.slf4j.LoggerFactory;
import org.springframework.stereotype.Repository;


    @Repository("customlistDAO")
    public class CustomListDAOImpl  implements CustomListDAO {

        private static final Logger logger = LoggerFactory.getLogger(CustomListDAOImpl.class);

        private SessionFactory sessionFactory;

        public void setSessionFactory(SessionFactory sf){
            this.sessionFactory = sf;
        }

        @Override
        public void addCustomList(CustomList customlist) {
            Session session = this.sessionFactory.getCurrentSession();
            session.persist(customlist);
            logger.info("list saved successfully, list Details="+customlist);
        }
}
```

CustomListService.java

```
    package main.java.com.bizmerlin.learningresources.services;

import main.java.com.bizmerlin.learningresources.model.CustomList;



public interface CustomListService {


     public void addCustomList(CustomList customlist);
}
```

CustomListServiceImpl

```
    package main.java.com.bizmerlin.learningresources.services;

import java.util.List;

import main.java.com.bizmerlin.learningresources.dao.CustomListDAO;
import main.java.com.bizmerlin.learningresources.model.CustomList;

import org.springframework.stereotype.Service;
import org.springframework.transaction.annotation.Transactional;



    @Service
    public class CustomListServiceImpl implements CustomListService {

        private CustomListDAO customlistDAO;

        public void setCustomListDAO(CustomListDAO customlistDAO) {
            this.customlistDAO = customlistDAO;
        }

        @Override
        @Transactional
        public void addCustomList(CustomList customlist) {
            this.customlistDAO.addCustomList(customlist);
        }


}
```

test.html

```
    <html>
<head>
</head>

<body>
<form action="localhost:9090/BMAppJ/customlist" method="POST">
 List name : <input type="text" name="listname" id="listname" value=""/>
customer id : <input type="text" name="cid" id="cid" value=""/>
<input type="submit" name="submitlist" id="submitlist" value="save"/>
</form>

</body>
</html>
```

and it is giving an exception :
exception

```
type Exception report
```

message

description The server encountered an internal error () that prevented it from fulfilling this request.

exception

```
javax.servlet.ServletException: Servlet.init() for servlet learning threw exception
    org.jboss.as.web.security.SecurityContextAssociationValve.invoke(SecurityContextAssociationValve.java:153)
    org.apache.catalina.valves.ErrorReportValve.invoke(ErrorReportValve.java:102)
    org.apache.catalina.connector.CoyoteAdapter.service(CoyoteAdapter.java:368)
    org.apache.coyote.http11.Http11Processor.process(Http11Processor.java:877)
    org.apache.coyote.http11.Http11Protocol$Http11ConnectionHandler.process(Http11Protocol.java:671)
    org.apache.tomcat.util.net.JIoEndpoint$Worker.run(JIoEndpoint.java:930)
    java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:744)
root cause

org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'customListController': Injection of autowired dependencies failed; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Could not autowire method: public void main.java.com.bizmerlin.learningresources.controller.CustomListController.setCustomListService(main.java.com.bizmerlin.learningresources.services.CustomListService); nested exception is org.springframework.beans.factory.NoSuchBeanDefinitionException: No qualifying bean of type [main.java.com.bizmerlin.learningresources.services.CustomListService] found for dependency: expected at least 1 bean which qualifies as autowire candidate for this dependency. Dependency annotations: {}
    org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.AutowiredAnnotationBeanPostProcessor.postProcessPropertyValues(AutowiredAnnotationBeanPostProcessor.java:292)
    org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.populateBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1185)
    org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.doCreateBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:537)
    org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.createBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:475)
    org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory$1.getObject(AbstractBeanFactory.java:304)
    org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.getSingleton(DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.java:228)
    org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.doGetBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:300)
    org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.getBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:195)
    org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultListableBeanFactory.preInstantiateSingletons(DefaultListableBeanFactory.java:700)
    org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.finishBeanFactoryInitialization(AbstractApplicationContext.java:760)
    org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.refresh(AbstractApplicationContext.java:482)
    org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.configureAndRefreshWebApplicationContext(FrameworkServlet.java:643)
    org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.createWebApplicationContext(FrameworkServlet.java:606)
    org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.createWebApplicationContext(FrameworkServlet.java:657)
    org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.initWebApplicationContext(FrameworkServlet.java:525)
    org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.initServletBean(FrameworkServlet.java:466)
    org.springframework.web.servlet.HttpServletBean.init(HttpServletBean.java:136)
    javax.servlet.GenericServlet.init(GenericServlet.java:242)
    org.jboss.as.web.security.SecurityContextAssociationValve.invoke(SecurityContextAssociationValve.java:153)
    org.apache.catalina.valves.ErrorReportValve.invoke(ErrorReportValve.java:102)
    org.apache.catalina.connector.CoyoteAdapter.service(CoyoteAdapter.java:368)
    org.apache.coyote.http11.Http11Processor.process(Http11Processor.java:877)
    org.apache.coyote.http11.Http11Protocol$Http11ConnectionHandler.process(Http11Protocol.java:671)
    org.apache.tomcat.util.net.JIoEndpoint$Worker.run(JIoEndpoint.java:930)
    java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:744)
root cause

org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Could not autowire method: public void main.java.com.bizmerlin.learningresources.controller.CustomListController.setCustomListService(main.java.com.bizmerlin.learningresources.services.CustomListService); nested exception is org.springframework.beans.factory.NoSuchBeanDefinitionException: No qualifying bean of type [main.java.com.bizmerlin.learningresources.services.CustomListService] found for dependency: expected at least 1 bean which qualifies as autowire candidate for this dependency. Dependency annotations: {}
    org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.AutowiredAnnotationBeanPostProcessor$AutowiredMethodElement.inject(AutowiredAnnotationBeanPostProcessor.java:596)
    org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.InjectionMetadata.inject(InjectionMetadata.java:87)
    org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.AutowiredAnnotationBeanPostProcessor.postProcessPropertyValues(AutowiredAnnotationBeanPostProcessor.java:289)
    org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.populateBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1185)
    org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.doCreateBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:537)
    org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.createBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:475)
    org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory$1.getObject(AbstractBeanFactory.java:304)
    org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.getSingleton(DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.java:228)
    org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.doGetBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:300)
    org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.getBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:195)
    org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultListableBeanFactory.preInstantiateSingletons(DefaultListableBeanFactory.java:700)
    org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.finishBeanFactoryInitialization(AbstractApplicationContext.java:760)
    org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.refresh(AbstractApplicationContext.java:482)
    org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.configureAndRefreshWebApplicationContext(FrameworkServlet.java:643)
    org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.createWebApplicationContext(FrameworkServlet.java:606)
    org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.createWebApplicationContext(FrameworkServlet.java:657)
    org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.initWebApplicationContext(FrameworkServlet.java:525)
    org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.initServletBean(FrameworkServlet.java:466)
    org.springframework.web.servlet.HttpServletBean.init(HttpServletBean.java:136)
    javax.servlet.GenericServlet.init(GenericServlet.java:242)
    org.jboss.as.web.security.SecurityContextAssociationValve.invoke(SecurityContextAssociationValve.java:153)
    org.apache.catalina.valves.ErrorReportValve.invoke(ErrorReportValve.java:102)
    org.apache.catalina.connector.CoyoteAdapter.service(CoyoteAdapter.java:368)
    org.apache.coyote.http11.Http11Processor.process(Http11Processor.java:877)
    org.apache.coyote.http11.Http11Protocol$Http11ConnectionHandler.process(Http11Protocol.java:671)
    org.apache.tomcat.util.net.JIoEndpoint$Worker.run(JIoEndpoint.java:930)
    java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:744)
root cause

org.springframework.beans.factory.NoSuchBeanDefinitionException: No qualifying bean of type [main.java.com.bizmerlin.learningresources.services.CustomListService] found for dependency: expected at least 1 bean which qualifies as autowire candidate for this dependency. Dependency annotations: {}
    org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultListableBeanFactory.raiseNoSuchBeanDefinitionException(DefaultListableBeanFactory.java:1100)
    org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultListableBeanFactory.doResolveDependency(DefaultListableBeanFactory.java:960)
    org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultListableBeanFactory.resolveDependency(DefaultListableBeanFactory.java:855)
    org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.AutowiredAnnotationBeanPostProcessor$AutowiredMethodElement.inject(AutowiredAnnotationBeanPostProcessor.java:553)
    org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.InjectionMetadata.inject(InjectionMetadata.java:87)
    org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.AutowiredAnnotationBeanPostProcessor.postProcessPropertyValues(AutowiredAnnotationBeanPostProcessor.java:289)
    org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.populateBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1185)
    org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.doCreateBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:537)
    org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.createBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:475)
    org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory$1.getObject(AbstractBeanFactory.java:304)
    org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.getSingleton(DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.java:228)
    org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.doGetBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:300)
    org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.getBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:195)
    org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultListableBeanFactory.preInstantiateSingletons(DefaultListableBeanFactory.java:700)
    org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.finishBeanFactoryInitialization(AbstractApplicationContext.java:760)
    org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.refresh(AbstractApplicationContext.java:482)
    org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.configureAndRefreshWebApplicationContext(FrameworkServlet.java:643)
    org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.createWebApplicationContext(FrameworkServlet.java:606)
    org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.createWebApplicationContext(FrameworkServlet.java:657)
    org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.initWebApplicationContext(FrameworkServlet.java:525)
    org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.initServletBean(FrameworkServlet.java:466)
    org.springframework.web.servlet.HttpServletBean.init(HttpServletBean.java:136)
    javax.servlet.GenericServlet.init(GenericServlet.java:242)
    org.jboss.as.web.security.SecurityContextAssociationValve.invoke(SecurityContextAssociationValve.java:153)
    org.apache.catalina.valves.ErrorReportValve.invoke(ErrorReportValve.java:102)
    org.apache.catalina.connector.CoyoteAdapter.service(CoyoteAdapter.java:368)
    org.apache.coyote.http11.Http11Processor.process(Http11Processor.java:877)
    org.apache.coyote.http11.Http11Protocol$Http11ConnectionHandler.process(Http11Protocol.java:671)
    org.apache.tomcat.util.net.JIoEndpoint$Worker.run(JIoEndpoint.java:930)
    java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:744)
note The full stack trace of the root cause is available in the JBoss Web/7.0.13.Final logs.

JBoss Web/7.0.13.Final
```

Comment: post your application context file

Answer (score 0):

Why using `@Qualifier(value="customlistservice")` when your service interface has only one implementation. Even if you use that you have to annotate

`CustomListServiceImpl` as

```
@Service("customlistservice")
public class CustomListServiceImpl implements CustomListService {
```

Also you haven't autowired dao in service class, you need to annotate it with @Autowired

```
    @Autowired
    private CustomListDAO customlistDAO;

    public void setCustomListDAO(CustomListDAO customlistDAO) {
        this.customlistDAO = customlistDAO;
    }
```

Comment: And I think @Autowired for sessionFactory in the CustomListDAOImpl  class is also missing?